# How save value in custom_attribute of "sale_order_grid"

Tags: magento2, order-grid

I have to save value in custom_attribute(current_seller_id) in "sales_order" table. using event below  code But now i want to save same value in custom_attribute(current_seller_id) of "sale_order_grid" table.
am new in magento guide me which observer or anything used for copy data from sales_order table to sales_order_grid.

```
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getData('order');
        $quote = $observer->getData('quote');

       // $cartdata=$this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem){
            if ($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId() != ""){
                $items[]=$quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId();
            }
        }
        $seller_ids=implode(',',$items);
        $order->setCurrentSellerId($seller_ids);
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following way will copy data automatically when saving sales_order table:

> VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="current_seller_id" xsi:type="string">sales_order.current_seller_id</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

[More details check this free module](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date)

Comment: Then accept answer, it will help others .